# ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors in [App]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, non-public-selectors

I am building a Xamarin.Forms app that is building properly and deploying to the Apple App Store but keeps getting rejected for the following reasons:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
> selectors in [App].Mobile.iOS: accessibilityBrailleMapRenderRegion,
> accessibilityBrailleMapRenderer, accessibilityColumnRange,
> accessibilityRowRange, activePlayer, beginAuthorizationWithRequest:,
> cancelAuthorizationWithRequest:, errorForCHIPErrorCode:,
> errorToCHIPErrorCode:, playerId, serviceExtensionWillTerminate,
> session:didReceiveData:fromPlayer:,
> session:didReceiveMessage:withData:fromPlayer:,
> session:player:didChangeConnectionState:, session:player:didSaveData:,
> setAccessibilityBrailleMapRenderRegion:,
> setAccessibilityBrailleMapRenderer:. If method names in your source
> code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method
> names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future
> submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may
> be located in a static library that was included with your app.

I coded the app on a PC in Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.9.1. And built and deployed the app via Appcenter.ms.

Packages that I am using are:

- Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics v4.5.0
- Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes v4.5.0
- Xamarin.Essentials v1.7.1
- Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.2337

Target Framework: .NET Standard 2.0

Information that I have confirmed from other sources:

- Build Configuration: Release
- Linker Behavior: Link Framework SDKs Only
- Additional mtouch arguments: --linkskip=[selectors]
- Additional mtouch arguments: --linkplatform

I have found all of the non-public selectors in `xamarin/xamarin-macios` and `xamarin/apple-api-docs` but I have not been able to find out how to fix the errors.

Thanks

Edit: I was not able to fix the issue. Instead, I got a Mac VM and was able to publish the code that way.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and i fix it by selecting (release | iphone) in the build options before archiving for publishing

Answer (score 0):

Add --linkplatform to the Additional mmp arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it didn't work. I got the same errors. I'll add that to the things that I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try add --linksdkonly to the Additional mtouch arguments on the iOS Build settings page

Refer from:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#link-sdk-assemblies-only

Comment: I tried that too with no success.

Comment: Like Meliza said,in the iOS build configuration, please set Configuration to release and Platform to iPhone.